# Movie: Grasshoppers from Space?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to remember a film about dead grasshoppers from space that were found in a British subway. Likely made in the late 50s or 60s. I remember there was a terrible noise that emanated from the area the creatures were discovered that drove the human characters mad, and that there was a fiery showdown at the end of the film with a giant live grasshopper... Archaeologists and the military were involved.

Comment: You really want to remember this film?  Sounds like this one sank into oblivion for good reason.

Comment: @KyleJones: Sometimes a film is so bad that it wraps around negative infinity and becomes super awesome. This movie actually sounds vaguely familiar to me.

Comment: @KyleJones LOL. Saying I'm trying to forget the film doesn't sound right.

Comment: This certainly didn't sink into oblivion. QATP is generally considered a classic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's the film version of [Quatermass and the Pit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quatermass_and_the_pit), which was released in the US as *Five Million Years to Earth*.

It was originally a TV series, and the series is [available on DVD](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Quatermass-Collection-Experiment-Pit/dp/B000772838/ref=sr_1_3). I strongly recommend the series as it is genuinely scary! The film version (Hammer studios?) is good, but not as good as the original.

Comment: Thank you. I looked it up. That's the one. It has an alternative title as well: *5,000,000 years to Earth*.

Answer (score 0):

Five Million Years to Earth is the movie in question.  Found the answer in a search that came up with an IMDB review of the movie.

Comment: Can you give evidence for this?

Comment: Please, state why you think this is the answer.

Comment: There is already an accepted answer for this question that gives essentially the same answer (alternate title of same movie).